# Mercurial served by RhodeCode

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, rhodecode

I've Mercurial and RhodeCode set up on an Ubuntu server. I follow [this manual](https://rhodecode.com/docs/setup.html) and start RhodeCode as described.

However, when I try to call the URL from a client, the server won't respond. I don't even see a message showing up on the server terminal suggesting that any kind of message arrived. I tried to install RhodeCode on my local machine and called 127.0.0.1:5000 and it just works fine. I see log messages in the console and the browser displays the page. Is there anything I miss or something that I can debug? (I tried netstat too and this service is listening to port 5000).

Comment: My RhodeCode setup on Windows 7 just started exhibiting this behaviour this morning, after working perfectly yesterday :P Firewall open on port 5000? And you might need to change `host` in your `production.ini` to your hostname, rather than (IIRC) 127.0.0.1. Alas, I'd already done this when mine decided to go down in flames :P

Comment: Yep - that's it. I had to use the remote IP rather than 127.0.0.1 as you said (the host name did not work). Cheers for the comment!

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if you've just solved my problem too... :)

Comment: Guys - put up a formal answer for others to enjoy. What fixed it...

Comment: @EldadAK shambulator already gave the answer: use the host name in `production.ini` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: An answer as a comment is hard to find. Posting an official answer is better for future searches. Just saying...